# Microsoft Power Point 2010 Cannot Propagate Page Number Footer on Master Slide

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint

I am making a power point template and I have a master, and dozens of slides under it. My master has a footer (Page Number)

```
[             <#>]
```

In the bottom right corner. (You can see this by opening up a blank presentation and viewing the master).

What I want to do is add some text such as

```
[ AUTHOR HERE <#> ]
```

and propagate this from my master to all the slides that inherit this master. But this doesnt work. It is absolutely dumb and ridiculous.

NOTE: I am aware of the functionality that I can do **Insert** -> **Header & Footer** -> **Check the right boxes** -> **Apply Changes to All** and this will come in handy when I want to reflect the change.

I can change the **Footer** and apply it in the Slide Master View and the Footer is updated. However, and this is the most frustrating part, when I add AUTHOR HERE to the Slide Number Part of the footer, those changes will not get reflected in the child slide!!

There is a fix, and it is to do it manually, but I would like this template to be dynamic so all you gotta do is change the name in the Page Number placeholder and it will update the rest of the template. I can make the PAGE NUMBER RED AND BOLD, I can move the Page Number place holder around and it updates the child slides accordingly, but when I add text into the box, it doesn't propagate! Why?!

Again, I'm trying a proof of concept from a default presentation.

I swear this is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the redesign from PPT 2003 to 2007, MS solved a rather small problem that affects a moderate number of people and in so doing, created a big problem that affects anyone who uses headers/footers/etc.  They haven't seen fit to fix it.

A couple of things:

I think you'll need to apply your "Author Here" text to the slide placeholder on each of the layouts (the "slides" indented beneath the main master in Master view).

To have the text apply, you'll want to go to Insert | Headers/Footers, remove the check next to Slide Number, click Apply to all.  Then repeat to put the check next to Slide Number again.  IOW, turn the slide numbers off then turn them back on again.  This forces them to regenerate.

Finally, just in case:  the <#> you see there isn't really a normal character, so typing <#> won't work.  If you type your "Author Here " and then while the text cursor's still in the text box, choose Insert | Date&Time, you'll get the correct character.

Comment: I'm curious about this "rather small problem"

Comment: Heh ... I *knew* somebody'd ask. ;-)  The problem was that if you used slide numbers (footers/dates too) on the slide master and then added anything in the same position on a slide, it'd cover up the footers/numbers/dates.  Now the footer stuff sits on top of everything on the slide, which is good, but it's also selectable, which is very bad.  They cured the mosquito bite on our ankle by cutting off our leg.

Comment: Ah. Oh well. I will have to do it manually. Still, what irks me is that it works for the footer. I.e. if you update something in the footer in the master it will get reflected on the subsequent slides. But not when you do it on the "page number" part of the footer! 

Manual it is

Comment: It should work identically for both (but again, you can't just type <#> for the number and expect it to work; it won't.  You have to use the Insert | Page Number command from the ribbon bar (or in code).  NB: I think that e.g. French PPT uses a different character for the page number "marker"

Comment: it doesnt work identically for both. If for instance I wanted to add <#> <#> (to the "Page Number" part of the footer, as you noted by going to Insert -> Page Number, and add this to the master, then it wouldnt get reflected. BUT, if I change the text "Footer" in the **Footer** part of the footer (yes, this can get confusing) these changes are reflected in all slides under the master

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. The text in the slide # placeholder on the master, once changed, doesn't propagate to all of the layouts.  I thought you were talking about the slides. You'll need to set it up as you want on the master, then copy/paste the placeholder to each of the layouts where you want it to appear, then in normal view, use Insert | Header & Footer to apply it to all of the slides.

Comment: Right, so if I wanted to change the author at the bottom each slide # footer, I would have to do so manually for each slide under the slide master. What i wanted was to create this in such a way that I hand it over to my colleague and all they'd have to do was change the "Author Here" to "Colleague Name" and it would propagate from the master to all slides.

Comment: Perhaps it'd make more sense just to and another bit of text to the master, position it next to the slide number, format it accordingly.  It'll appear on every slide automatically.

Comment: you mean like a "text placeholder? i dont think those are possible on the master.

nevermind. that just exactly solved my problem. I thought I had to insert a placeholder as under the "slide master" tab

Comment: No, not a text placeholder.  Just a text box.  Anything you add to the master (other than slide numbers, it seems) will appear on all slides.